# In New Relic how to download client specific dashboard as PDF

Tags: newrelic

I have a new relic dashboard which shows Total-Requests, 200, 400, 500 responses and i have 1 more tile showing client names , assume names as client-1, client-2, client-3 which is of type bar. Now assume i received 70 requests as shown below

| Client | no of req's |

| -------- | -------------- |

| client-1    | 30            |

| client-2   | 40            |

i can download as pdf containing all 70 requests, Now there is a option in tile showing client names "FILTER THE CURRENT DASHBOARD" when this is enabled it shows client specific data like, client-1 specific data showing about 30 requests which is good & expected and filter is also reflecting on top. Now when i tried to download this filtered dashbord as pdf it is showing the overall data of 70 records which is wrong , the downloaded pdf should show only 30 requests. Help how i can download client specific data dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately NR don't have such features. You may setup NRQL bases alerts but that will give you data bases on the query result.

However you can use the following alternative:
https://github.com/AnthonyBloomer/dashboard-email-scheduler/

From this approach you can Periodically share a New Relic Dashboard.